# Docker-compose with containerized nodejs + mysql "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.144.3:6002"

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

My application have several containers, two of which needs a connection between them. 1 is a nodejs server called `users_service` the other is a mysql container called `db`

upon running `docker-compose up` it throws this error. My understanding is that the `users_service` container couldn't connect with the `db` container

```
users_service                           | Server started successfully, running on port 80.
users_service                           | Unhandled Exception Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.144.3:6002
users_service                           |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16) {
users_service                           |   errno: -111,
users_service                           |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
users_service                           |   syscall: 'connect',
users_service                           |   address: '192.168.144.3',
users_service                           |   port: 6002,
users_service                           |   fatal: true
users_service                           | }
users_service                           | Unhandled Exception Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
users_service                           |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:114:31)
users_service                           |     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
users_service                           |     at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:715:12) {
users_service                           |   fatal: true,
users_service                           |   code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
users_service                           | }
```

i tried all the things i could including, specifying ports, expose, looking around stackoverflow forums but still couldn't find anything helpful.

These are some key files.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  asset_mapping:
    build: asset_mapping
    ports:
      - "28017:27017"

  asset_mapping_seed:
    build: asset_mapping_seed
    links:
      - asset_mapping

  asset_service:
    build: asset_service
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    depends_on:
      - asset_mapping
    links:
      - asset_mapping
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=asset_mapping
      - PORT=8008

  users_service:
    build: user_account_service
    container_name: users_service
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db:db
      - asset_service:asset_service
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - PORT=80

  db:
    build: user_data
    ports:
      - "6002:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
```

db Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 123
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE users
ENV MYSQL_USER users_service
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD 123

# seeding
ADD ABCompany.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

users_service Dockerfile

```
# Use Node v4 as the base image.
FROM node:17-alpine 

# Add everything in the current directory to our image, in the 'app' folder.
ADD . /app

# Install dependencies
RUN cd /app; \
    npm install

# Expose our server port.
EXPOSE 80

# Run our app.
CMD ["node", "/app/index.js"]

WORKDIR /usr/app
```

the users_service/config/config.js file (used to save connectionSettings to the db container)

```
//  config.js
//
//  Simple application configuration. Extend as needed.
module.exports = {
    port: process.env.PORT || 80,
  db: {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'ABCompany',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123',
    port: 3306
  }
};
```

the repository (mysql database) users_service/repository.js file

```
//  repository.js
//
//  Exposes a single function - 'connect', which returns
//  a connected repository. Call 'disconnect' on this object when you're done.
"use strict";

var mysql = require("mysql2");

//  Class which holds an open connection to a repository
//  and exposes some simple functions for accessing data.
class Repository {
  constructor(connectionSettings) {
    this.connectionSettings = connectionSettings;
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection(this.connectionSettings);
  }

  getUserByUsername(username) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //  Fetch the customer.
      this.connection.query(
        "SELECT username, phone_number FROM user_profile WHERE username = ?",
        [username],
        (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(
              new Error("An error occured getting the user: " + err)
            );
          }

          if (results.length === 0) {
            resolve(undefined);
          } else {
            resolve({
              username: results[0].username,
              phone_number: results[0].phone_number,
            });
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
  
  disconnect() {
    this.connection.end();
  }
}

//  One and only exported function, returns a connected repo.
module.exports.connect = (connectionSettings) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!connectionSettings.host) throw new Error("A host must be specified.");
    if (!connectionSettings.user) throw new Error("A user must be specified.");
    if (!connectionSettings.password)
      throw new Error("A password must be specified.");
    if (!connectionSettings.port) throw new Error("A port must be specified.");

    resolve(new Repository(connectionSettings));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, it seems that your Express application is attempting to connect to a database on port 3306, but your database container is actually exposed on port 6002. To resolve this issue, you can take one of two approaches:

- Change the port that your Express application is using to connect to the database to match the exposed port of the container (in this case, 6002).
- Change the exposed port of your database container to match the port that your Express application is trying to connect on (in this case, 3306).

I also recommend using environment variables to adjust your database connection parameters in your Express application, and specifying the values in Docker environment variables rather than hardcoding them. This will make it easier to manage and configure your application in different environments.